# How to call multiple base classes __init__ in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have doubt if multiple classes inherited to a derived class. How can we call the **init** of all base classes.

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor of Base1 Class')

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor of Base2 Class')

class Base3(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor of Base3 Class')

class Derived(Base1, Base2, Base3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived, self).__init__()
        print('Constructor of Derived Class')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   inst = Derived()
```

When i run the above code. I get the output as below

```
Constructor of Base1 Class
Constructor of Derived Class
```

I think Base2 and Base3 `__init__` are not getting called. Is there a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a proper way to do it:

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor of Base1 Class')

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor of Base2 Class')

class Base3(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Constructor of Base3 Class')

class Derived(Base1, Base2, Base3):
    def __init__(self):
        Base1.__init__(self)
        Base2.__init__(self)
        Base3.__init__(self)
        print('Constructor of Derived Class')
```

Output:

```
inst = Derived()
Constructor of Base1 Class
Constructor of Base2 Class
Constructor of Base3 Class
Constructor of Derived Class
```

Source:
https://www.journaldev.com/14623/python-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Accepting yours as answer as you have also provided a link which explained more about the inheritance

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `super()` in each constructor so that it calls `__init__()` from  list of `_mro_`

```
class Base1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Constructor of Base1 Class')

class Base2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Constructor of Base2 Class')

class Base3(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Constructor of Base3 Class')

class Derived(Base1, Base2, Base3):
    def __init__(self):
        #  super(Derived, self).__init__()
        super().__init__()
        print('Constructor of Derived Class')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   inst = Derived()


Constructor of Base3 Class
Constructor of Base2 Class
Constructor of Base1 Class
Constructor of Derived Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i have implemented this. But accepted Elya Fadeeva as answer, bcoz the help link he provided gave me much more infor in inheritance.